# Why do browsers fail to fetch a css referenced in an external svg from server?

Tags: css, reference, svg, element, external

Hello I am working on an svg/js map, which consists of many little svg graphics (City districts). I put every graphic into an own file so that my main svg file will still be maintainable and not bloated. Additionally all svgs share the same css file.

I use an image tag to reference another file, which itself references a css file.

Expected result: Open 1.svg in a browser and see a blue rectangle.

I  tested the map app **as local files** where **it just worked as intended** but when I uploaded the application to a web server **the browsers failed to load the css from the server** - Firefox shows an unstyled version of the svg while opera shows nothing at all and says it is still loading element 2/2. It does not matter, if I upload it to my local apache or use dropbox for testing.

So here are the SVGs:
1.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-       20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"    width="1000" height="1000">
<image xlink:href="another.svg"/>
</svg>
```

another.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-       20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg id="rectangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"    width="1000" height="1000">
<rect class="blue" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>
```

style.css

```
.blue { fill: blue; }
```

You can use http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40969346/stackoverflow/reference/1.svg to test it yourself.

Comment: Haven't looked at the DTDs, but the W3C's examples have the stylesheet reference coming BEFORE the doctype declaration: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html   swap yours around and see what happens?

Comment: weird! BTW http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40969346/stackoverflow/reference/another.svg does show blue. Try changing <?xml-stylesheet href="style.css?another" type="text/css"?> in another.svg and see if that makes the external style for the 2nd svg file load and apply? Adding ?another would make the browser act as if that were a different file and not the one already loaded into the first svg file.

Comment: @Wayne Weird indeed. I tried "style.css?another" - has no effects .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not experiencing any issues locally, it sounds to me like it might be something as simple as a missing MIME type. The correct one for SVG is: image/svg+xml.

Comment: The MIME type is right: Content-Type: image/svg+xml. The problem is not that the svg doesn't load, it is the css that doesn't.